# How to find the newest entry for each of "n" with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm working on fixing up a forum script of mine, and I want to do what many popular sofwares do and display the latest reply for each board category on the category list.

I just can't seem to get something that only gets one per category, or gets the newest. I can get one or the other, just not both.

My latest attempt was this:

```
db.session.query(Post)\
    .order_by(Post.id)\ 
    .group_by(Post.category)\
    .all()
```

...which resulted in one per category, but only the oldest in each. I've tried it with both descending and ascending order, neither seemed to work how I want them to.

**Table information**

Post(id,author,title,post,postedon,edited)

Category(id,name,description,weight)

Is it possible to reverse the order the posts are listed in for the group_by? I feel that would get me right where I needed to be.

Answer (score 1):

After much fooling about, I've found a way to do this.

```
posts = db.session.query(Post.id)\
    .order_by(Post.id.desc())\
    .correlate(Category)\
    .filter(Category.id == Post.category)\
    .limit(1)\
    .as_scalar()

categories = db.session.query(Category, Post).filter(Post.id == posts).order_by(Category.weight)
```

I've no idea if this is the *best* way to do this, but at least it works.